# How can we Let VC++ to automatically determine the best alignment size using __declspec?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In GCC you can you can leave out the alignment factor and just ask the compiler to align a type to the maximum useful alignment for the target machine you are compiling for:

```
    struct S {
       short f[3]; 
    } __attribute__ ((aligned));
```

How can I do the same for Visual Studio C++ compiler using  **__declspec**??
all that can be done is to explicitly provide the alignment size such as:

```
__declspec(align(#)) // where # is the alignment size in bytes
```

and the MSDN says:

> Without **__declspec(align(#))**, Visual C++ generally aligns data on natural boundaries based on the target processor and the size of the data, up to 4-byte boundaries on 32-bit processors, and 8-byte boundaries on 64-bit processors. Data in classes or structures is aligned in the class or structure at the minimum of its natural alignment and the current packing setting (from #pragma pack or the **/Zp** compiler option).

Dose this means that the **maximum useful alignment** is the **natural boundaries** in this case?

Comment: @Olaf I am not spamming tags, a C expert might by chance answer my question

Comment: Tags are not to attract maximum attention, but to correctly sort/find questions. Take the [tour].

Comment: @Olaf , understood,  thank you for clearing this out

Comment: What does "maximum useful alignment" mean?  (Serious question btw).  I understand what "natural alignment" means in this case.

Comment: Interesting comment about "up to 4-byte boundaries on 32-bit processors" - I thought `double` performed significantly worse if it wasn't 8-byte aligned.

Comment: @MartinBonner the alignment that  optimize memory and  maximize the allocation speed for the target machine .... I think this matches the cache alignment

Comment: If you are allocating from heap, in Windows an object will (I think) always be pointer aligned, or two-pointer aligned.  If you are allocating from the stack, memory allocation speed is a constant.  In that case there is no benefit to aligning to more than the underlying object alignment..

Comment: @MartinBonner maybe I'll just use the MSDN specs and  then try without the alignment statement and compare the performance